# System Settings window is not accessible

Tags: icons, system-settings, gnome-control-center

[System setting icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekpnS.jpg)I am using 18.04, and **system settings** window is not accessible but icon is appearing. I have tried every method available on askubuntu but none of them is working. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "setting" and what "methods" have you tried to do what? Your question is not understandable

Comment: I have edited my post for your understanding. I have tried all the methods available on askubuntu for the same issue faced by others.